# CSS: question about radio button

Tags: css, radio-button

I have this [page](http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs2/web/index.php).

If `<input>` is and inline element why goes down the second radio button (Chico) ??

Regards

Javi

Comment: Without some html and css code is really difficult to see why. Which type of <input> are you writing about?

Comment: @mamoo - it's all there on the page he's linked to.

Comment: BTW your HTML code looks unnecessarily complex. It would probably much easier to format those forms with tables.

Comment: @RoToRa it's not good practice to use tables for layout. Tables should be reserved for representing tabular data.

Comment: Many people argue that a form like this **is** tabular data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try left floating the unordered list containing the radio buttons:-

```
ul.radio_list { float: left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `display:inline` on your `li` elements (the containers for your radio buttons).

Comment: FYI - i just did (using Firebug), and it fixes your problem.